# Is there any way to start Disciples II on Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, disciples-2

I'm having troubles trying to start Disciples II on Windows 10.
I can open the game, but it is very slow. I've tried:

- Running it on XP mode and 800x600
- XP on Virtual
- Disabling my graphics card and playing using only the processor's base graphics

I really love this game, is there any way I can play it properly on Windows 10?

Comment: Is it possible its your copy of the game?

Comment: What do you mean? The game is oryginal if you need to know

Comment: It could be that the game itself has a problem, have you tried re-downloading it?

Comment: Oh in that way sorry for my priviois answer.  Yrs i try IT first i install Frombork cd them from internet same problem on both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open the game configuration (configeditor.exe is located in your disciples 2 folder) and try checking `Use Direct 3D` and/or `Compatibility Mode`